# Swipe back to dismiss delete button on UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have enabled swipe to delete tableview cell.
When I swipe, delete button shows up and to dismiss the delete button at the moment I need to tap the tableview cell or any other cell.

I am looking at an option to swipe back the cell to dismiss/hide delete button.